# With a Driving Attack, can you attack a target you did not push?

Tags: dnd-4e

The fighter's Driving Attack says:

> **Driving Attack**
>
> You drive back your adversary with a hail of blows.
>
> Daily
>   Invigorating, Martial, Weapon
>   Standard Action      Melee weapon
>   **Target:** One creature
>   **Primary Attack:** Strength vs. AC
>   **Hit:** 2[W] + Strength modifier damage, and you push the target 1 square. You then shift 1 square to a square the target vacated. Make a secondary attack
>   against the target.
>   **Secondary Attack:** Strength vs. Fortitude
>   **Hit:**
>   1[W] + Strength modifier damage, and you push the target 2 squares and
>   knock it prone. Miss: Half damage, and you push the target 1 square.

Me and my adversary are standing in difficult terrain and if I push the target, I won't be able to shift into the vacated square. Therefore, I  will choose not to push the adversary. Therefore, I won't be able to shift into a vacated square. Will I be able to make use of the secondary attack anyway?

Comment: Somewhat related: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/38319/can-i-skip-the-shift-and-slide-from-luring-strikes-hit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

All forced movement is optional, and there is no conditional on this power that forces you to attack only after you've pushed the opponent.

> When a distance is specified, it is a maximum; the creature or effect producing the forced movement can move its target up to that number of squares (or none at all). For instance, a character’s power might say, “You slide the target 4 squares (or “up to 4 squares”); both mean the character can move the target up to 4 squares or not move it at all. ([RC 311](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=176))

So we have the forced movement as clearly optional, movement on powers is also always optional.

The only thing left to evaluate is the trigger of the attack. The line "Make a secondary attack on the target" is disconnected from the previous sentence that provides for the shift and slide.

There is nothing here to prevent you from making the secondary attack if you decline the push + shift.